# Getting status of 400 - {"error":"invalid_grant"} On Authentication

Tags: javascript, c#, api, oauth

I created my own website ([www.luig.us](http://www.luig.us)). I create a basic IDE for SQL server to teach kids SQL, DML only.

It requires the user to enter an username and password at the beginning to get an token to use the service.

On local, everything works fine, but when I put it on my site, hosted by go-daddy, I will get the same message every time and I don't have a clue why.

> {"error":"invalid_grant"}

This is my java script code - look for Authorize. Any help is appreciated.
I followed this article closely https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2/

```
function Authorize() {
    let bearer = "Basic Q01JUzMwOERTMzA4OndlYkFQSQ=="
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var userNameAndPasswordFilled = (email != "" && password != "");
    if (!userNameAndPasswordFilled) {
        $("#formError").show('fast');
    }
    else {
        var bodyOfRequest = {
            grant_type: "password",
            username: email,
            password: password
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: uriManager.access,
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", bearer);
            },
            data: bodyOfRequest,
            success: function (response) {
                sessionStorage.setItem(programKeyWords.BearerToken, response.access_token);
                $('#LogonModal').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $("#formError").show('fast');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if the base64 encoded string contains your actual credentials for Basic Authentication, then you should change them immediately. Having them base64 encoded is no more secure than having them in clear text. If you used fake credentials for the question then never mind.
Now to your question. Which OAuth provider or Authorization Server are you using? have you implemented it yourself?

Comment: in regards to the bearer token, I really didn't know how to handle that part of the process. Any guidance is appreciated.

I followed these steps https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2/

Yes, I implemented myself.

Comment: Have you updated on your Program class the value of the baseAddress? [step 6](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2/) @FrancoPettigrosso

Comment: You did not provide server code. By the way, you don't need that "bearer". Your site is public and hardcoded "secret" like that doesn't do anything useful anyway.

Comment: yea, I tried it with postman as well

Comment: As far as server code. What would you like to see? From my understanding. That error is coming before my code is even touched.

Comment: Is uriManager.access an url to your site? If so, what code actual executes when you call it?

Comment: You should post the server side function which recive/validates the token

Comment: If the bearer token presented in this question is a real credential, then you should change it immediately, [edit] it out, and flag your post for moderator attention so moderators can purge the credentials from the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the code. The problem was with:

1. The connection string. It was not correct.
2. I was encrypting the username and password and it wasn't matching correctly because of special characters

What I did to fix it.

1. fixed the connection string
2. fixed the algorithm to store a hash instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much without more information but first thing I would check is if you actually have users in your database (or whatever oauth you're using).  The error you're getting can likely be caused if you don't actually have a user with that username and password in your oauth database.

The endpoint you're using for `uriManager.access` is where you have to check if that user actually exists.